"TypeScript Error: Property 'comparePassword' does not exist on type 'Document<unknown, {}, IUser> & IUser' in Mongoose Model"
I'm developing a LMS in Node.js application along with TypeScript and Mongoose. I have defined a user schema and model, and I'm trying to add a custom method comparePassword to the user model for password comparison during user login. However, I'm encountering a TypeScript error:
this is user.controller.ts:
require("dotenv").config();
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";
import userModel, { IUser } from "../models/user.model";
import ErrorHandler from "../utils/ErrorHandler";
import { CatchAsyncError } from "../middleware/catchAsyncError";
import exp from "constants";
import jwt, { Secret } from "jsonwebtoken";
import ejs from "ejs";
import path from "path";
import sendMail from "../utils/sendMail";
import { createWatchCompilerHost } from "typescript";


// Login User
interface ILoginRequest{
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

export const loginUser = CatchAsyncError(async(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) =>{
  try {

    const {email,password} = req.body as ILoginRequest;

    if(!email || !password){
      return next(new ErrorHandler("Please Enter the email and password",400));
    };

    const user = await userModel.findOne({email}).select("+password");

    if(!user){
      return next(new ErrorHandler("Invalid email or password",400))
    };

    const isPasswordMatch = await user.comparePassword(password);
    if(!isPasswordMatch){
      return next(new ErrorHandler("Invalid email or password",400));
    };

  }
   catch (error:any) {
    return next(new ErrorHandler(error.message,400));
  }
})

this is user.model.ts:
require('dotenv').config();
import mongoose, { Document, Model, Schema } from "mongoose";
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";
import { promises } from "dns";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

const emailRegexPattern: RegExp =
  /^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/;

export interface IUser extends Document {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  avatar: {
    public_id: string;
    url: string;
  };
  role: string;
  isVerified: boolean;
  courses: Array<{ courseId: string }>;
  SignAccessToken: () => string;
  SignRefreshToken: () => string;
}

const userSchema: Schema<IUser> = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "enter your name"],
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "enter your email"],
      validate: {
        validator: function (value: string) {
          return emailRegexPattern.test(value);
        },
        message: "please enter a valid email",
      },
      unique: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "enter your password"],
      minlenght: [6, " Password must be at least 6 characters"],
      select: false,
    },
    avatar: {
      public_id: String,
      url: String,
    },
    role: {
      type: String,
      default: "user",
    },
    isVerified: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    courses: [
      {
        courseId: String,
      },
    ],
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

// hash Password before adding in database
userSchema.pre<IUser>("save", async function (next) {
  if (!this.isModified("password")) {
    next();
  }
  this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10);
  next();
});

// sign access token
userSchema.methods.SignAccessToken = function(){
  return jwt.sign({id: this._id},process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN || '');
};

// sign refresh token
userSchema.methods.SignRefreshToken = function(){
  return jwt.sign({id: this._id},process.env.Refresh_TOKEN || '');
};

// compare password
userSchema.methods.comparePassword = async function (
  enteredPassword: string
): Promise<boolean> {
  return await bcrypt.compare(enteredPassword, this.password);
};

const userModel: Model<IUser> = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

export default userModel;


error shows at :
const isPasswordMatch = await user.**comparePassword**(password);
    if(!isPasswordMatch){
      return next(new ErrorHandler("Invalid email or password",400));
    };

in user.controller.ts as:
"Property 'comparePassword' does not exist on type 'Document<unknown, {}, IUser> & IUser & Required<{ _id: unknown; }>'.ts(2339)"
here's screenshot of code :enter image description here
here' screenshot of error: enter image description here
I'm trying to create a login portal to my Learning management system and I encountered this error while writing a code to compare entered and stored password using active and refresh token.
